# Regex Groups - Words subset of each other

Tags: regex

I am using regex to read the values of a line and all is has been well.  (date,description, type and amount)

```
08/12 TO BAC#48307986457 Withdrawal 3,000.00
08/12 FROM BAC#48307986453 Deposit 3,000.00

^(\d{2}\/\d{2}) ([A-Za-z0-9\-\&\#\s]+) (Withdrawal|Deposit) (\d+([\d,]?\d)*(\.\d+))
```

Now I hit where the Withdrawal adds "Pre-Authorized" to become "Pre-Authorized Withdrawal" which conflicts with "Withdrawal"

```
08/06 UNIVERAL HEALTH Pre-Authorized Withdrawal 62.00
```

I have tried many things like adding Pre-Authorized as an optional but no suceess.

I can get one or the other - never both.

Regex is new for me so I am appreciative of any advice.  thank you.

Comment: Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/DEcQJb/1). Made the subpattern(that match the description) lazy and added optional `Pre-Authorized`

Comment: i had tried the optional ()?  put not with the (?:)?.  Not really sure what is does - but it works.  Amazing.  thank you so much!!!

Comment: `(?:)` is a [non capture group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges)

Comment: Yes, it is a non-capturing group. In your original regex, the subpatterns for matching the description and type are not mutually-exclusive. The subpattern written for capturing `description` is greedy so it matches as many characters as possible, thus overshooting the "boundary" between `description` and `type` and capturing `Pre-Authorized` within the `description`

Comment: You don't have to use capture groups: you could instead split the string on matches of the following regular expression: `(?<=\d{2}\/\d{2}) +| +(?=(?:Pre-Authorized )?Withdrawal|Deposit)| +(?=[\d,]+\.\d{2})`. After confirming the array returned has four elements those element will respectively equal the date, description, type and amount.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v9Nf8S/1). Hover the cursor over each part of the regex at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the only exception, you can make that part optional in the pattern.

Also note that for the amount you don't need all those capture groups, and yo can rewrite it to get a bit more precise match.

The character class does not need escapes for the `\&` and `\#`, and depending on the delimiters for the pattern, you don't have to escape the forward slashes as well.

```
 ^(\d{2}/\d{2}) ([A-Za-z0-9&#\s-]+) ((?:Pre-Authorized )?Withdrawal|Deposit) (\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d+)$
```

See an updated [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/97aasi/1).